# my webservice restful client fail post c# bearer

Tags: c#, rest, post

I Write one application to access one Webservice Restful using C#, i get the Token with success, i access other services without parameters fine, but when i need to send parameters in POST method it´s not work.
In other side, the Wesbservice dont see my post.
Can someone help-me about this ?
Here is my code.

```
        string urlMethod = metodo;
        //    "/api/v1/organizacao/criar";

        var accessToken = IntegraPb.GetToken();

        var client = new RestClient(Sincronizador.Properties.Settings.Default.apiUrl);

        var request = new RestRequest(urlMethod, Method.POST);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        var jsserie = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        // obj is my class to serialize
        request.AddJsonBody(jsserie.Serialize(obj));

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

[This image is the request object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsUAh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AddJsonBody](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/a9a2b8ad4490897b7378c987be6532d866de55f0/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L278) receives a object, not a serialized string of your object. It does the serialization internally.

So use this instead:

```
request.AddJsonBody(obj);
```

Comment: could you  accept my answer as the answer and maybe upvote it? =)